# Add content type machine name as body class

Tags: theming, nodes

Is there a way to insert a class to the body of the node page? It should be named like the current node type's machine name.

Maybe someone could extend this code below with a content type class:

```
function marienschule_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

  // Add node ID to the body class.
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  if ($node) {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'node-' . $node->id();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code sample from your question could be extended to look like that:

```
function marienschule_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {

    // Add node ID body class.
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'node-' . $node->id();

    // Add content type machine name body class.
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'node-type-' . str_replace('_', '-', $node->bundle());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this without a preprocess hook, because the node type variable is already available in the html template:

```
{%
  set body_classes = [
    logged_in ? 'user-logged-in',
    not root_path ? 'path-frontpage' : 'path-' ~ root_path|clean_class,
    node_type ? 'page-node-type-' ~ node_type|clean_class,
    db_offline ? 'db-offline',
  ]
%}

...

<body{{ attributes.addClass(body_classes) }}>
```

Source: *[html.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21themes%21classy%21templates%21layout%21html.html.twig/8.6.x)* of Classy